# group_vars/all syntax error

Tags: json, syntax-error, ansible

I am having a group_var/all file whose starting lines look exactly like this :

```
##################################
['./roles/openssh/defaults',
 './roles/rsyslog/defaults',
 './roles/tomcat8/defaults',
 './roles/oracle_java/defaults',
 './roles/psp_db/defaults',
 './roles/provision_kill_instance/defaults',
 './roles/kill_app/defaults',
 './roles/base/defaults',
 './roles/ntp/defaults']
##################################

base_google_dns_enabled: false
```

when i run it as **ansible-playbook provision_aws.yml**  it throws a error :

```
ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, /home/nsingh/ansible-psportal/group_vars/all
Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 13, column 1


base_google_dns_enabled: false
```

According to my diagnosis , this is because of the things inside [] , even if i put this at the end of my group_vars i encounter something similar. Any Help Would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax looks incorrect.  Try:

```
---
myroles:
  - './roles/openssh/defaults'
  - './roles/rsyslog/defaults'
  - './roles/tomcat8/defaults'
  - './roles/oracle_java/defaults'
  - './roles/psp_db/defaults'
  - './roles/provision_kill_instance/defaults'
  - './roles/kill_app/defaults'
  - './roles/base/defaults'
  - './roles/ntp/defaults'
base_google_dns_enabled: false
```